# Looking for sites that describe minimalist writing for technical content

Tags: technical-writing

I'm looking for a site or sites that describe minimalist writing ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism_(technical_communication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism_%28technical_communication%29)). The Wikipedia article is so minimalist it doesn't provide such links.

If you employ this technique and can point me to some useful that explain it, I would appreciate it.

thanks,
Linda

Comment: While providing a list of sites really appropriate for a Q&A site (since there's no way to definitively answer the question) maybe we can still be of help. Can you explain why you want to know this? What information are you looking for? Is this for a specific writing project or are you just looking for general information?

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about the minimalist approach to technical writing, what it's principles are. Google searches tend to pull stuff on minimalist art period.  I guess I don't really understand why a list of sites wouldn't be considered an answer. Is it not the role of a Q&A site to point people to resources? I've seen style manuals and links to books in some answers.

Comment: Those are older questions, if they were asked now they'd probably be closed. But your edit is much  more specific, thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia page provides a list of seven books on the topic. Why don't you pick them up and read them?

Comment: Some information isn't online ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not employ the technique but here are a few web links that I have found about the use of minimalism in technical writing:

- A discussion on the principles of minimalistic writing as described by Carroll  http://everypageispageone.com/2013/07/02/what-is-minimalism/
- A brief discussion by IBM: http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=1745125&seqNum=5
- Using minimalism: http://www.tcworld.info/rss/article/minimalism-in-documentation/
- Brief discussion and bibliography: http://users.edte.utwente.nl/meij/minimalism.htm
- Assessment of the minimalist approach to computer user documentation [PDF Document] http://doc.utwente.nl/26433/1/Meij93assessment.pdf
- Few more resources here: http://tc.eserver.org/dir/Articles/Documentation/Technical-Writing/Minimalism
- Minimalism: Does it work for expert users? http://tier1.wordpress.com/tag/technical-writing/
- The art of saying less: Minimalism http://www.technicalwritingireland.com/blog/the-art-of-saying-less-minimalism-3/
- Why minimalism matters (may not be too relevant) http://www.publishingsmarter.com/resources/books-and-articles/why-minimalism-matters
- A course on minimalistic writing: http://www.stc.org/education/online-education/certificate-courses/item/minimalist-writing

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the Android online documentation:
[Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). It's a "training" that leads you through doing a task, but it's not a tutorial since it doesn't show you how to do a particular app.